# How to pass data to EJBContext on client side?

Tags: java, ejb

I have following interceptor on server:

```
@Resource
EJBContext ejbContext;

@AroundInvoke
public Object onInvocation( InvocationContext aInvocationContext ) throws Exception
{
    final Object myValue = ejbContext.getContextData().get("MyKey");
    ...
    Object proceed = aInvocationContext.proceed();
    ...
    return proceed;
}
```

How to pass data ("MyKey") to EJBContext on client side?
I tried to lookup it but I get **javax.naming.InvalidNameException**' exception during lookup or **EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available** when I call getContextData(). I tried several ways I do not know If I do something wrong or **EJBContext** is some special resource and It is not possible to modify it on client.

How lookup name should look like?I tried **java:comp/EJBContext**, **appName/moduleName/EJBContext**.

Comment: do you find the solution?

Comment: I added answer 1 minute ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created client interceptor.

```
EJBClientContext.requireCurrent().registerInterceptor( 0, new MyClientInterceptor() );
```

There is important note in **registerInterceptor** method javadoc:

> Note: If an interceptor is added or removed after a proxy is used,
> this will not affect the proxy interceptor list.

MyClientInterceptor:

```
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInterceptor;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext;

public class MyClientInterceptor implements EJBClientInterceptor
{

    @Override
    public void handleInvocation( EJBClientInvocationContext aContext ) throws Exception
    {
        Object myValue =...
        aContext.getContextData().put( "MyKey", myValue );
        aContext.sendRequest();

    }

    @Override
    public Object handleInvocationResult( EJBClientInvocationContext aContext ) throws Exception
    {
        return aContext.getResult();
    }
}
```